# org.hibernate.QueryException: unindexed fromElement before []

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
Class A {

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "A_join_C", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false, updatable = false))
@OrderBy(value = "createdTime ASC")
public Set<B> getB() {
        return this.b;
    }

}

class B {

private C c;

}

class C {

String name;

}
```

Trying to filter Class A based on name in C

using

```
Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)
```

in QuerydslPredicateExecutor

The error thrown is something like

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unindexed fromElement before []: a.b [select a
from com.app.model.A a
where a.b[0].c.name = ?1 and a.b[0].c.task = ?5 .....]
```

Found a link related to this issue here

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=993438&view=next

Changed the Set to List and tried, but still the same error. Not sure why this error happens

Answer (score 1):

Just making it a `List` is not enough, you also need to replace `@OrderBy` with `@OrderColumn`. This makes the list an indexed list which then can make use of the index access notation.